# MySQL tree structure query and joining a other table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need some help with a MySQL / MariaDB query. I have two tables, a `user` table and a `reward` table.

`user` table, storage for users who can referral other users. By doing so, they are getting rewarded.

`reward` table, storage / history for rewards. Rewards are based on level's, level 1 is getting more rewards then level 2, level 3 etc..

Now I would like to have a stored procedure that gives me the following result based on two values:

Input:

1. root user Id
2. max level of rewards

Output:

```
+------+-----------+----------+--------+
| id   | name      | rewards  | level  |
+------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    4 | parent 1  |       75 |      1 |
|    4 | parent 1  |        0 |      2 |
|    5 | parent 2  |        0 |      1 |
|    5 | parent 2  |        0 |      2 |
+------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

id --> user id
name --> users name

rewards - level 1 --> total rewards that this referral has raised

rewards - level 2 --> total rewards that this referral has raised

rewards - level 3 --> ...

I already did some investigation and was thinking of a RCT (Rrecursive Common Table) for getting the user tree structure and joining the outcome on the rewards table. Writing the RCT isn't that difficult but iam getting stuck on joining the reward table. Do I have to use a CTE there too?

Any sugestions on the query as well on the database structure is welcome.

Please find the SQL fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXs5F6s62JyRn9hWBkc2pj/1

Comment: What did you try with the [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (Common Table Expression)?

Comment: Because Recursive CTE was introduced in [MySQL8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), and you use 5.7 ? (at least that's the version used in the fiddle...)

Comment: Iam using the latest version of MariaDB (10.7.3). The reason why the fiddle is in 5.7 is because I couldn't find a fiddle with a higer version, at least not one that actually worked.

Comment: A dbfiddle with MariaDB (version 10.6) is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=ddc641e78b551726023d1058758a7fb4).   Can you share some more info on the fields `user1` and `user2`? How should they be interpreted?

Comment: Sweet, one that works, thanks! About the fields `user1` and `user2`, They are there to keep track of what reward is given to what user on what level.
For instance, user `child 1` has achieved a certain goal. Because he achieved that goal, his referral `parent 3` is rewarded with X. As `parent 3` is referred by 'grandparent 2', 'grandparent 2' is also rewarded with Y. Hope this makes sense.